# Why can container IDs be abbreviated in docker but not image tags, container names or image digests?

Tags: docker, digest, abbreviation

Given, on the repository I have a situation like this:

```
$  docker images
REPOSITORY                    TAG                  IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
myrepo:5000/myimage           latest               1c3c75da38df        3 days ago          546MB
myrepo:5000/myimage           20181130-CET183709   1c3c75da38df        3 days ago          546MB
myrepo:5000/myimage           20181126-CET191306   b143d325cd0e        7 days ago          846MB
myrepo:5000/myimage           20181122-CET190934   ccf40fb5ec0f        11 days ago         746MB
```

And a container running:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
73d78cb7d34e        myrepo:5000/myimage "uwsgi --plugin http…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:9090->8443/tcp   heuristic_noyce
```

I can do:

```
docker exec -ti 73d7 bash --login              # works - shortened container ID
```

but not:

```
docker exec -ti heuristic bash --login         # fails - shortened container name

docker exec -ti heuristic_noyce bash --login   # works - full container name
```

I can **not** pull a docker image by shortened digest like so:

```
docker pull myrepo:5000/myimage@sha256:b143d   # fails - shortened image ID (digest)
```

Pulling a docker image by shortened tag also fails:

```
docker pull myrepo:5000/myimage:20181126            # fails - shortened tag

docker pull myrepo:5000/myimage:20181126-CET191306  # works - complete tag
```

**Why not allow abbreviations for all of these?**

Is there a workaround? I mean I'd understand it failing, when there were two or more tags starting with `20181126`, but in cases where it is unambiguous? Where would I make a feature request for that?